# STL Vector data extraction

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a `std::vector<char>` that has a size of around `1500`. But when i try to use `vector::data` to extract the data to a string, it doesnt work.

```
std::vector<char> testVector;
//insert data to test vector
std::string temp = testVector.data();
```

when I print `temp` after this, it just prints `DATA`. When I reduce the size of `data` in `vector` to 100-200, it works normally and as expected. But when the size increases, it stops working. I tried using `string::reserve`, still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: your "vector" has to be null-terminated

Comment: Does your vector contain a `\0` anywhere? It should contain at least one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assigning a `char*` to a string requires a null-terminated string.

To copy a (not null-terminated) `vector<char>` into a `string`, use:

```
std::string temp(testVector.data(), testVector.size());
```

or (this is more idiomatic as it can work with any container):

```
std::string temp(testVector.begin(), testVector.end());
```

Comment: It seems like you should prefer this form generally, as string operations generally go much faster when the size is known up-front.  If you _do_ know the string in your `vector` has a NUL terminator, but you do not want that in the resulting `string`, you can always adjust the size you pass to `string`'s constructor appropriately.

Comment: Another option (which is more container neutral) is `std::string temp(testVector.begin(), testVector.end())`

Comment: @Dave S: Edited in 10 seconds before your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
std::vector<char> testVector;
//insert data to test vector
testVector.push_back('\0');
std::string temp = testVector.data();
```

Your problem likely occure to the fact, that the c string you are constructing `temp` with is not null-terminated. C strings must be null-terminated in order to have some notion about an end. You can read up more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string